# Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить прозрачность картинки, на фоне другой картинки

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скажите, пожалуйста
  картинка тучки имеет .png формат
  но белыйй фон остается, нужно его убрать

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.bgr1
{
    background: rgb(109, 166, 165);
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 18vh;
    z-index: 2;
}
  .bgr2
    {
     background : white;
     width : 100%;
     height : 100vh;
     }

  .btn{
      margin-left:0px;
      margin-top:0px;
      
       width:170px;
       display: inline-block;
       height:100%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
     
      font-family:sans-serif;
      font-size:24px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
      
      text-align:center;
      line-height:12vh;
       margin-left:0px;
       margin-top:0px;
       margin-right:0px;
       margin-bottom:100px;
      vertical-align:middle;
       padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
      transition: 0.2s;

  }
   .btn:hover { background: rgb(62, 134, 146);}
  .vhod
  {
        margin-left:0px;
      margin-top:0px;
      
     background:no-repeat;
       
       display: inline-block;
          
       box-sizing: border-box;
       position:absolute;
       width:6px;
      font-family:sans-serif;
      font-size:22px;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
      
      text-align:center;
      
       margin-left:0px;
       margin-top:40px;
       margin-right:0px;
       margin-bottom:100px;
      vertical-align:middle;
       padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
      transition: 0.2s;
      background-image:url(../pictures/login.png);
      
  }
  

 
  

  /*font sans-serif*/
```

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Main</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="bgr1">

            <img src="~/pictures/report.png" alt="альтернативный текст">

                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Про сервіс</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Можливості</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">ЕЦП</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Ціна</a>
                <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">Контакти</a>

                <a class="vhod" href="@Url.Action("Registration","Home")"></a>


        </div>

        <div class="bgr2">

            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <style>
                .text {
                    text-align: center;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 47%;
                    left: 37%;
                    font-family: Calibri;
                    font-size: 32px;
                }
                .text1 {
                    text-align: center;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 75%;
                    left: 41%;
                    font-family: Calibri;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
                .btn_Sprobuv_Bezkosh {
                   
                  margin-left:0px;
                   margin-top:0px;
      
      
       
                 
       
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 60%;
                    left: 37%;
     
                  font-family:Calibri;
                  font-size:28px;
                  text-decoration:none;
                  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
                  border-radius: 6px;
                  background: rgb(255, 0, 220);
                  text-align:center;
                  line-height:6vh;
                  margin-left:0px;
                  margin-top:0px;
                  margin-right:0px;
                  margin-bottom:100px;
                  vertical-align:middle;
                  padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
                  transition: 0.2s;
    
            }
                .btn_Sprobuv_Bezkosh:hover { background: rgb(208, 0, 146);}
            </style>

            <div class="text1">
                
                    <strong>REPORT</strong><br>
                    звітуйте електронно<br>
               
            </div>
            <img src="~/pictures/w128h1281372334742football.jpg" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;" alt="альтернативный текст">
            <img src="~/pictures/hmarka.png" style="position:absolute;left:708px;top:270px;" alt="альтернативный текст">
            <img src="~/pictures/hmarka.png" style="position:absolute;left:743px;top:296px;width:75px;" alt="альтернативный текст">
              
            <a class="btn_Sprobuv_Bezkosh" href="@Url.Action("Main","Home")">спробувати безкоштовно</a>

            <div class="text1">
                <strong>
                    
                        Онлайн-сервіс<br>
                        формування, подання та зберігання<br>
                        електронної звітності<br>
                        для юридичних та фізичних осіб<br>
                        підприємців<br>
                   
                    </strong>
          </div>

        </div>
             <div class="bgr3">

            </div>
        </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картинка должна иметь прозрачный фон, а не просто PNG формат.

Comment: а как добавить прозрачность фона?

Comment: @Dualist opacity пробовали?

Comment: https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/5380872/post403062269/

Comment: opacity меняет прозрачность самой картинки а не background

Comment: Alex78191, я убрал фон и сохранил в png

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу картинку.

Comment: добавилллллллллллл

Comment: Никакого белого фона нет https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmaJRa

Comment: ахах не обновил страницу спасибо!)